# Monitoring /etc/passwd file

Tags: linux, bash, redhat

I need a script that will check any modification in the `/etc/passwd` file, if there's a modification I get alerted immediately via email telling me that a user that has been added or removed from the `passwd` file

Without using inotifywait command

Comment: check `inotify` usage

Comment: Make a copy of the passwd file in a location and use a cron to do a  diff on the current and the copy that you made, if any differences , it can send out a mail. you can set the cron to about 15 mins or as per your requirement. Is this what is required?

Comment: Or maybe use the auditd package if you have. https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html might be useful

Comment: You'll need to explain what prevents you using the inotify interface, else it looks like mere capriciousness on your part.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help].  It may be better suited to the [unix.se] Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could check for modifications with md5sum or sha256...
make your base checksum, hardcode it in a scrip

`if [[ "$(sha256 /etc/passwd)" != "the hash of ori file" ]]; then
  mail yourself
fi`

you could also have a copy of /etc/passwd somewhere and run a diff that you send by mail as to have the content of the changes

`if [[ "$(diff /etc/passwd /root/passwdbackup)" != "" ]]; then
  mail yourself
fi`

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `inotifywait` utility, something like this:

```
inotifywait -e modify /etc/passwd
```

`inotifywait` will exit when the selected file is written, so you can take whatever action you need.

Comment: i dont have inotifywait on my machine

Comment: How you install it depends on the Linux distribution you are using. If you are unsure, best to ask on a sysadmin forum -- that isn't a programming question.

Comment: On ubuntu and linux mint `apt install inotify-tools`. On arch `pacman -S inotify-tools`.

Comment: I dont want to use any installed packeges, my server is not connected to the internet

Comment: Not making this any easier for yourself, are you? ;) Write a script that runs `stat -c %Y /etc/passwd` to get the last modification time in seconds. Store that value and wait for, say, one minute. Repeat. If the modification time is different, take some action.

Comment: Or, since this would also detect writes that did not change anything, store the checksum (`cksum` or `md5sum`) instead. Checking the modification time will be quicker, however